# opencv/C++: Place a saved image over a webcam stream with facial recognition

Tags: c++, image, opencv, face-recognition, imshow

I am trying to figure out how to place a saved image over a webcam stream in C++.

The trick is that I want to place the image over a face and whenever the face moves, the image will move. I was able to draw a circle over a face with my code here:

```
Point center = Point(faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.45);
circle(captureFrame, center, faces[i].width / 1.65, cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0), 50, 8, 0);
imshow("outputCapture", captureFrame);
```

However, I would like to display an image (test_image.jpg) over my captured webcam frame (captureFrame) on the person's face using the Point function to always find the center of the face.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: this might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67985080/4622046

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Sikuki library by MIT:

http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devs/system-design.html

Comment: I would rather have all my functionality remain inside opencv, preferably using the ROI/Mat functionality somehow.. I am just not sure how