# How to listen to an event using sockets?

Tags: c++, sockets, video-streaming, client-server, cgi

We are trying to add **play/pause/record** buttons to a webpage that shows a video stream.

The video is streaming from the server and the webpage is on the client-side.

Now the client can see the video stream on the webpage, but we wanted to add some buttons. This is the code that sends the video using sockets:

```c
void stream(cv::Mat* frame){
    TCPServer serverInputConnection("localhost", 8080);
    serverInputConnection.createListener();

    ////////////////////// reconnect network cycle //////////////////////
    while(1)
    {
        if(serverInputConnection.waitConnect() == TCPServer::STATE_ERR)
        {
            cout << "reconnect...\n" << endl;
            sleep(2);
            continue;
        }
        // read HTTP header
        serverInputConnection.readMsg();
        cout << "Client header:\n" << serverInputConnection.inMsg.data() << endl; // show http header
        serverInputConnection.inMsg.clear();

        cout << "start stream" << endl;

        // send http header
        string headImg;
        headImg += "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
        headImg += "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n";
        headImg += "Pragma: no-cache\r\n";
        headImg += "Connection: close\r\n";
        headImg += "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=jpegboundary\r\n\r\n";

        while(1){
            vector<unsigned char> jpgBuff;
            jpgBuff.clear();
            std::vector<int> params;
            params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
            params.push_back(50);

            imencode(".jpg", *frame, jpgBuff, params);

            // send http separation
            headImg += "--jpegboundary\r\n";
            headImg += "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n";
            headImg += "Content-length: " + to_string(jpgBuff.size()) + "\r\n\r\n";
            std::vector<char> strBuff(headImg.begin(), headImg.end());


            headImg, serverInputConnection.Msg = strBuff;
            if(serverInputConnection.sendMsg()!= TCPServer::STATE_OK)
            {
                break;
            }

            headImg.clear();

            // send image
            if(serverInputConnection.sendMsg(jpgBuff) != TCPServer::STATE_OK)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    serverInputConnection.disconnect();
}
```

and this is the code for the TCPServer functions:

```c
TCPServer::status TCPServer::createListener()
{
    isConnect = false;

    // create socket
    sockIn = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockIn < 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR opening socket\n" << endl;
        return currentState = STATE_ERR;
    }

    int yes=1;
    //char yes='1'; // use this under Solaris
    if (setsockopt(sockIn, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1)
    {
        cout << "setsockopt\n" << endl;
        return currentState = STATE_ERR;
    }
    if (setsockopt(sockIn, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1)
    {
        cout << "setsockopt\n" << endl;
        return currentState = STATE_ERR;
    }

    bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //any incoming messages
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(localPort); // is old function

    //serv_addr.sin_port =  bswap_16(localPort);

    // select listen port
    int bindRes = bind(sockIn, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (bindRes < 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR on binding\n" << endl;
        return currentState = STATE_ERR;
    }

    cout << "listen input port: " << localPort << endl;

    if(listen(sockIn, 5) != 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR on listen socket\n" << endl;
        return currentState = STATE_ERR;
    }

    return currentState = STATE_OK;
}
```

### Questions:

1. How can we know when the user clicks a button? (e.g. if the user clicks on **pause** we want to stop the streaming).
2. What is the best way to do this? (***cgi, socket, PHP, another way***)

Comment: You'll have to do a fair bit of development, draw the buttons in HTML, with an action that sends an ajax request to the server, identifying the stream to be paused, and then implementing the appropriate code on the server side that receives the ajax request and does whatever needs to be done.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you. We can create the buttons but don't know how to receive the ajax request from the client (because the server code is in C++).

Comment: There's nothing strange about an ajax request that prevents it from being implemented in C++, or any other language.

Comment: @hg255 use xmlhttprequest/fetch or 3d party libs like axios to send get/post request to the server according to your needs and handle it on the server.